# Has SO's development time ever been discussed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange-history

I tried searching but couldn't find anything.  Has it been discussed on how about how long Stack Overflow's time from initial development to beta was?  I know they were working on it part-time for a while which is why I am interested if they've mentioned it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some discussion about it on the early episodes of [the podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html).  In [episode 16](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail3754.html) they answer the listener question:

> Why did the Stack Overflow schedule blow out?

Answer (score 3):

6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Simply Obligatory.

Comment: http://sixtoeightweeks.com